# Parameterized FIFO instantiation in Verilog

Tags: verilog, xilinx, fifo, synthesis

I wanted to have a parameterized FIFO instantiation so that I can call a single FIFO instance with change in depth(parameter).

e.g. I have written a code for FIFO with depth as a parameter.

I will know the depth of the FIFO only by the configuration from Microprocessor. Based on the register configuration, can i call this FIFO with variable parameter like value?

```
integer depth_param;
 if(config_reg[1])
   depth_param <= 128;
 else
   depth_param <= 512;

 genfifo #(depth_param) (.din (din),.wr(wr)....);
```

fifo module is:

```
 module gen_fifo #(depth = 128)
 ( din,wr,rd,clk....);
```

can you please suggest is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Just make a tap in your fifo at position 128, then make a switching logic that will use data from tap in case of config_reg[1] = 1, else use data from fifo end.

Comment: A parameter needs a constant value. The value cannot change after compilation or synthesis. The name `config_reg` implies a register, something that is load after compilation/synthesis. Is `config_reg` a register or parameter?

Comment: @Sergei: you can't do that. Everything changes when you change the FIFO depth -  address pointer wrap-around, AE, EF, AF, FF flags - you can't just take data from the middle. The OP must create a complete run-time configurable FIFO.

Comment: I doubt you can create "runtime" configurable FIFO. What is runtime in hardware world? Just a bunch of FF and wires. At most you can cover several constant cases.

Comment: @Sergei - it's straightforward - program your FIFO depth into a register, and use that register as the limit test in the RW pointers, instead of testing against a constant. Similarly, the flags are derived against the register, instead of being derived against a constant.

Comment: @EML Yes, this is kinda what I suggest, constant or register does not really matter if you are designing everything yourself. However the author seems to be using a macro generator and is struggling to make it accept non-constant parameters. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Sergei - think you're right - the OP is probably using a macro generator and will instead have to code the FIFO from scratch.

Comment: Hi @Sergei, You are right. I am using a macro from microsemi. I thought of giving a try to dynammically change the FIFO width by changing the threshold value in the FIFO macro. Unfortunately, microsemi macro does not provide the threshold signal either. Thank you all for youe responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the LRM says:

> Parameters represent constants; hence, it is illegal to modify their
>   value at run time. However, module parameters can be modified at
>   compilation time to have values that are different from those
>   specified in the declaration assignment. This allows customization of
>   module instances. A parameter can be modified with the defparam
>   statement or in the module instance statement. Typical uses of
>   parameters are to specify delays and width of variables.

'run time' means during simulation, after elaboration. A synthesiser doesn't 'run' anything, but what you're doing is effectively "run time", and so is illegal.

This doesn't mean that you can't do it, though. Pass in your FIFO depth as a module port. I'm assuming that you know how to code a FIFO from first principles. If so, you will normally have a constant for the FIFO size; just replace this constant with the value at the port, and find some way to set the memory size. You'll obviously need to be careful when changing the FIFO size - you may need to reset it, for example. If you don't know how to code a FIFO you should ask with an FPGA or an electronics tag.